# Are there any problems with this use of a Provider instead of a StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, provider, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;

  const Example({super.key, required this.children});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ScrollController>(
      create: (_) => ScrollController(),
      child: ListView(
        controller: context.read<ScrollController>(),
        children: children,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Same with the TextEditingController.

This approach seems more concise to me, but some of my colleagues do not share my views.

Comment: Provider is also using Stateful widget under the hood but its better to use not StatefulWidget . Besides u don't need to use ChangeNotifierProvider, instead u can do this Provider.of<class>(context, listen: true);  this listen parameter will do the state changing work under the hood

Comment: Your answer is not very clear, I can’t replace ChangeNotifierProvider with Provider.of, because ChangeNotifierProvider creates an object and Provider.of... reads it or watches, these are absolutely opposite things, and I use ChangeNotifierProvider because ScrollController extends ChangeNotifier and Normal Provider does not fit here

Comment: got it, Theb can u give any hints about what they r prefering instead urs

Comment: StatefulWidget with initState and dispose to create and dispose controller